# SQL/DB browser for DB2

Tags: windows, browser, sql, query, db2

I'm looking for a simple SQL browser which supports DB2. I just want to be able to connect to a DB and try some queries.

Comment: Which OS is your client on?

Comment: Apologies, should have added a tag with the os. Windows..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBvisualizer supports DB2 as well as most databases, IBM Data Studio or DB2 Control Centre are specific for DB2. You can download and use them all free.

Comment: However, IBM Data Studio is the only that provides control for db2 features, like compression, pure scale, dpf, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try MS office - Excel and Access have MSQuery which allows simple SQL queries through ODBC..

If your keys are correct then it will automatically join tables using foreign keys to the primary key in the other table - but you can override these if needed.